# Server requests class in Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

A java class that I have written to send requests to my server on 000webhost isn't working. I'm getting deprecated http elements so my code won't compile. I've tried changing my api level but that did nothing useful, it just stopped my gradle from building.
Here's the java class I'm talking about :

```
package com.mu.cs.loginregister;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by John on 10/12/2015.
 */
public class ServerRequests {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://www.thenameofmyserver.com/";

public ServerRequests(Context context){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
}

public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
}

public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callback){
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callback).execute();
}
public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

        Map<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
        dataToSend.put("name", user.name);
        dataToSend.put("age", user.age + "");
        dataToSend.put("username", user.username);
        dataToSend.put("password", user.password);

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost (SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(null);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User>{
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Map<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
        dataToSend.put("username", user.username);
        dataToSend.put("password", user.password);

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost (SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

        User returnedUser = null;

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if (jObject.length() == 0){
                user = null;
            }else{
                String name =jObject.getString("name");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                returnedUser = new User(name, user.username);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(returnedUser);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
    }

}
}
```

I also wrote two php files to store in my database that this code would talk with.

PHP1:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $age=$_POST["age"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $username=$_POST["username"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statment);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PHP2:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli=connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db);

    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT" * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statment, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $user[name] = $name;
        $user[age] = $age;
        $user[username] = $username;
        $user[password] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);

    mysqli_stmt_close($con);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any help with why this isn't working will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not try using non-deprecated http elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HttpURLConnection` instead of deprecated Apache library.
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#http

or add to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client